# How to install something that requires pub install using Flutter SDK?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to compile https://github.com/dart-lang/protobuf/tree/master/protoc_plugin

According o the ReadMe, I should just run `pub install`. I have the flutter SDK that should include the Dart SDK.

I tried:

```
flutter pub install

Could not find a subcommand named "install" for "flutter pub".
```

and

```
dart pub install

Error: Error when reading 'pub': No such file or directory
```

and

```
pub install

/bin/sh: 1: pub: not found
```

How can I compile it using the flutter SDK?

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, but try `flutter pub pub install`

But `install` is the same as `get`. Not sure why those docs say to use `install`.